# AngularJS callback, copy the behavior of $http. Turn cache into promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, callback, angular-promise

I want to create a cache for my http requests, so I want to duplicate the $http callbacks.

this is my function:

```
function getData() {
    if(cacheExists()) {
        return cache;
    }

    return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://something.com',
            params: {something}
        });
}
```

and this is how I handle it:

```
  getData()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.spot = data.data;
            console.log($scope.spot);
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log('error');
        });
```

this will work perfectly with angularjs $http method,
but will not work with my "cache", becuase the "cache" should have those callbacks: success & error, how do I create them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because the $http returns a promise. You can solve this by using the $q service and return the cache as a promise.

```
//inject $q
function getData() {
   var deffered = $q.defer()
   if(cacheExists()) {
      deffered.resolve(cache);
   } else {
       $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://something.com',
            params: {something}
       })
      .success(function(data) {
         deffered.resolve(data);
       })
      .error(function(response) {
        deffered.reject(response);
      })
   }

    return deffered.promise;
}
```

So what's happening here that you are creating "deffered" as a promise. A Promise is basically a way to handle async tasks. And when you get a promise you need to resolve it, as you did with your return value from the http call. But with a $q deffered you are using 'then' instead of 'success'. Consider the code snippet below:

```
getData()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.spot = data.data;
        console.log($scope.spot);
    })
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
As of you example by handling errors you could do this:

```
getData()
    .then(function(data) {
        if(data.data) {
            $scope.spot = data.data;
            console.log($scope.spot);
        } else {
            console.log("its an err");
        }
    });
```

Or this

```
getData()
    .then(successCallback, errorCallback);

function successCallback(data) {
    $scope.spot = data.data;
    console.log($scope.spot);
}

function errorCallback() {
  console.log("its an err");
}
```

Comment: and sorry... what is $q, and how do I inject him?

Comment: Well, how you would handle the http errors is probably depending on the usecase i guess. You inject $q where you inject $http, in controller and/or service. Where ever you have implemented the getData function.

Comment: yes of course depends on the case, but I mean that now I only have ".then" callback, so I don't know if it's an error or success...

Comment: You can pass in two callback. One successcallback and an errorcallback. Let me update the example.

Comment: I'll try to dive in to it, hope I'll understand, thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool. You can read more about $q in the angular docs. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q